# What Are The Elements Of $(A\times B)^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we are given two sets $X=\{1,2\},Y=\{1,2\}$ and $ \{1\}=A\subset X, \{2\}=B\subset Y$

So $A\times B=(1,2)$ so what will be $(A\times B)^c?$ can it be $(1,1)?$

Comment: You mean $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$?

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes sorry, edtied

Answer (score 3):

$$A \times B=\{(1,2)\}$$

$$X \times Y=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$$

So, $$(A \times B)^c=\{(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)\}$$